# Pros and cons of using one project for multiple apps in Firebase Could Messaging

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

In our company, we have many apps for Android and for iOS. And we want to use Firebase for push notifications. So, do we need to create new **project** in Firebase for each app, or will be better just use one project with all apps inside? What are pros and cons both ways?

First way:

- App1 Firebase project

  - App1 Android Dev
  - App1 Android Stage
  - App1 iOS Dev
- App2 Firebase Project

  - .....

Second way:

- Company firebase project

  - App1 Android dev
  - App2 Android stage
  - App2 iOS Dev
    ...

Which is better?

Comment: Please edit your question to be more specific about the relationship between all your apps.  Are they all using the same data in the Firebase project?  Do you need to send Cloud Messages to all of them at the same time?  Do they have the same logged in users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new project, it will have an android app inside of it. If you want to create the application also for ios and/or web, then you need to go to the Overview page and click <kbd>add another app</kbd>. Then all the apps inside a project will be able to access one database.

Therefore it is better to add all of the production applications to one project, so they can access the same database.

If you want to create apps for testing/development then create another project and add the apps inside of it, as specified here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/configure/

Comment: Sure, but if it's different types of apps. Let's imagine one app is Instagram, another is Facebook. Should I add them to one project, or separate?

Comment: no seperate projects, as I said all apps in one project will have access to the same database

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. Are there any drawbacks of putting many unrelated apps in the same Firebase project (eg. Facebook, Twitter, Reddit...), assuming that all we need from Firebase is FCM, no database?

Comment: @samzmann  see this question for instance. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61668088/fcm-send-messages-to-topic-in-specific-app  I think it can be done, but with some care and caution to not mix things up .